Reorder Teams Channels and hide some channels inside Teams desktop application for all users
I have this Teams, which contain standard channels and private channels:-

now i want to re-order those channels for me and for all users accessing the teams? is this possible? and how? i am the Teams owner.
Second question. I am an Owner of a Teams, and the Teams has those channels:-

Now i want to totally hide "Chanel Three" from all users Teams' desktop app? how i can do so?
Thanks

AFAIK, channels are listed in alphabetical order.
While you can drag to arrange the actual Teams showing on the left, you can't re-arrange channels inside a team.
Plan ahead and name the channels accordingly, so they appear in the order you want.
Users can hide or show the channels they belong to. There is no setting to hide a channel from all members of the team. What purpose would that serve? Teams is for sharing, not for hiding. If you need a separate channel that is not visible to the team members, then don't put that channel into that team.

ok thanks a lot for the useful reply . for hiding the channel , maybe i can consider removing the permission for all users from that channel ?

If you would like to share the channel with limited users from the Team, try Private channels.

Agree with teylyn, there is no option to re-order channels in the Teams. You could remove permissions for all users from that channel to hide it.

What would be the point of a channel if you hide it from the team members? The very purpose of a Team is to share information and documents. If you want to limit the audience, just create another team for just that limited audience. Work WITH the product, not against it.
